# Pass values into session.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to pass some values into session.php.

Below is my code. `type_oq` is a dropdown menu. I want to save certain values if the dropdown selection is equal to "fruit".

The problem: Not sure what is the problem. No errors shown. The php file path is accurate. Button click works. My guess is that there might be a syntax error in the if condition?

```
  $('#goBtn').click(function(){
    alert("done!");
    $.post('sessions.php',
      {
        if ($('#type_oq').val() == "fruit") {
          a:$('#a_oq').val(),
          b:$('#b_oq').val(),
        }
        from:$('#from_oq').val(), 
        to:$('#to_oq').val(),
        radioG:$('#radioGroup').val()
      } ,

      function(response) {
        $('#postrequest').html(response);
      });
  });
```

Comment: I've personally never seen an ajax request performed in this way. I don't think, however (not sure though) that you can use an if operator into the $.post

Comment: @briosheje: thanks. how would you go about passing values depending on a dropdown value?

Comment: I would check the values first by putting them into some variables and THEN perform the request, let me try with an answer below :)

Comment: Also, there is a syntax error.. but, moreover, just a side question: what happens if $('#type_oq').val() is NOT fruit? is your php script expecting something? I'm going to assume that if it is not fruit, then a and b are null.

Comment: if ` $('#type_oq').val()` is NOT fruit the rest gets $post (from,to,radioG)

Comment: Ok, but the question is not on the client side, but on the server side. if sessions.php is expecting a and b, then you should be providing them :)

Comment: anyway, Niklas already did it ;)

Comment: @briosheje appreciate your input. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the `data` object outside the `$post` and then just pass it as a variable:

```
  $('#goBtn').click(function(){
    alert("done!");
    var data = {
        from:$('#from_oq').val(), 
        to:$('#to_oq').val(),
        radioG:$('#radioGroup').val(),
        // If a and b are required then create them here with empty values.
        a: "",
        b: ""
    };
    if ($('#type_oq').val() == "fruit") {
        data.a = $('#a_oq').val();
        data.b = $('#b_oq').val();
    };

    $.post('sessions.php', data, function(response) {
        $('#postrequest').html(response);
    });
  });
```

Just to be extra clear, it turns out that you can't use conditions inside of the object creation, e.g. this wouldn't work:

```
var data = {
  if (true) {
    a:"a", 
  }
  b: "b"
};
```

Comment: was about to post something like that. However, since we don't know how sessions.php is, we may eventually have to set a and b in any case.

Comment: You're right. If they are required they should be added from the start, with some default values.